# Neo4j desktop installer stuck on choose path where you want to store application data

Tags: powershell, neo4j, neo4j-desktop

I am trying to install neo4j on my windows 11 Laptop.

But the neo4j desktop installer just gets stuck on **choose path where you want to store application data**

[image]

Clicking on confirm or changing the directory dosen't do anything.

As per some solutions recommended in similar stack overflow questions, i added this path to system env variables

```
C:\Windows\System32\wbem
```

But this also didn't solve any of the problems.

After some debugging, i found out the exact error log in the developer console.
[image]

It seems like neo4j isn't using wcim but Get-CimInstance command which is throwing the error.
I have no idea how to fix this problem.